# Where can I find old (historical) FIR map?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airspace, icao

I'm doing a research with FIR Ho Chi Minh (formerly named FIR Saigon).

I've read a document which said:

- During the Fall of Saigon, ICAO, in 28th of April 1975, had divided FIR Saigon into 3 AOR: Bangkok, Singapore and Hongkong, then they gave these AOR to the corresponded FIR.
- In the 7th of December, 1994, ICAO sent AOR Bangkok and AOR Singapore back to FIR Ho-Chi-Minh.
- In the 1st of November, 2001, ICAO gave part of AOR Hongkong to FIR Ho-Chi-Minh, and created AOR Sanya from the remained part of AOR Hongkong.
- In the 8th of June, 2006, ICAO changed AOR Sanya to FIR Sanya

I managed to search those old FIR maps in the internet but no luck for me.

Hence, I would like to find out all historical FIR maps to make a comparison.

If it is impossible to find all FIR maps, old FIR maps of South East Asia FIR is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hate to say this, but I think your only help might be an old pilot who used to fly in those days. If you live inside one of the regions, you may try your luck at the local library looking for publications of the aviation authority dated back to those years.

Comment: @kevin I really hate it if it is the truth.

Comment: In the continuation of @kevin comment: You may also try the national library, if there's one, which registers any publication for research. You could look for ATC training books (such library would be the Library of Congress in the US, the [National Library](http://nlv.gov.vn/ef/en/#) in Viêt Nam).

Comment: Please get in touch with ICAO/Air navigation/Aeronautical Information and Charts at the ICAO HQ in Montreal, Canada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best I can find is a ATC radar screen used in a dated report (appears to be [a report by the Hong Kong Civil Aviation Department in 2000](http://www.cad.gov.hk/reports/an2000-2001/Chapter03.pdf)). It shows the FIR regions and waypoints of near Hong Kong, Hainan island and Vietnam:

[image]

Here is a dated enroute chart of Hong Kong in 1996. I'm not sure if the waypoint names will be useful for your further search:
[image]

---

How I end up with these: for the first one I used keyword "Sanya AOR". Given the dates you stated in the question, Kai Tak airport was still operational during that time. So I searched for charts of Kai Tak. A full set of charts of the airport would contain an "enroute chart" which lists waypoints. Search engine is Bing.

Comment: I have just found this document http://www.icao.int/APAC/Meetings/2011_FIT_SEA11_and_SEACG18/SEACG18-WP10.pdf It seems like that it used the old map dated back to 2000 or before. Then, I concluded that in the shape with SQ0866 was belonged to FIR Hongkong, now part of it belonged to Hongkong and remain part belonged to Sanya. The shape with a lot of islands was belonged to FIR Ho-Chi-Minh, now part of it belonged to Sanya, remaining part belonged to FIR Ho-Chi-Minh.

Comment: 1 vote for you  but I will leave this as unanswered. So, we can continue on this find.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This is a photo from the 1954-1955 Hong Kong Civil Aviation Department Annual Report

Maybe too late to post, but I just want to share it on the internet as a record.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.stackexchange.com! Nice find!